# Model invalid return partial view without main view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my EspaceClient/Compte.cshtml I retrive a partial view.
It works but when the ModelState is not valid, I retrieve only the partial view without his main view.

Thank you

```
function partialCoordonnees() {
        $.ajax({
        url: '/Utilisateurs/Edit/'+ @Model.Id,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
         $('.fifth').html(data);
        }
        });
};
```

In my UtilisateursController

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
     Utilisateur utilisateur = db.Utilisateurs.Find(id);
     return PartialView("_CoordonneesCompte", utilisateur);
}


public ActionResult Edit(Utilisateur utilisateur)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(utilisateur).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "EspaceClient", new { id=utilisateur.Id  });
    }
        return PartialView("_CoordonneesCompte", utilisateur);
}
```

Comment: Check the rendered HTML -- it is probably the full page inserted within the target element. AJAX will not follow a redirect request. If you want a redirection you will need to check the response for the 302 redirection and navigate with javascript in your callback.

Comment: The first call the partial view is in the full page $('.fifth').html(data);
The problem is in this return PartialView("_CoordonneesCompte", utilisateur) when the model is not valid.
I didn't know how I do what you thold me

Answer (score 1):

do not perform server side validation with **ModelState.IsValid**

go for client side validation with unobstrusive jQuery library

add **jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js** and **jquery.validate.min.js**  in your cshtml

[Example]

```
//this code goes in your partialview
$(function(){ 
  //allow the validation framework to re-prase the DOM
  jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse(); 

  //or to give the parser some context, supply it with a selector
  //jQuery validator will parse all child elements (deep) starting
  //from the selector element supplied
  jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#formId");
});


//then in your parent page handle the form submission
$(function(){
  $("#SubmitButton").click(function(){ 
    if (!$("#Form1").valid()){ 
      return false; 
    } 
  });
});
```

this example taken form [Here](http://code.davidferguson.me.uk/post/47540738095/mvc-client-validation-after-partialview-loaded-via)

Hope it helps you...